# Thickness of Depletion region, transistor

Tags: transistors, diodes

I came across a doubt regarding thickness of Depletion region in different regions of transistor while reading an online article. It says that the thickness of Depletion region in collector is more than base, but i think thickness in base should be more because it is lightly doped, am I correct?[image: screen shot from the site]

Answer (score 4):

No, you're incorrect.

The Doping doping levels are:

E: highest doping level

B: less than E

C: weakest doping, less than B

It needs to be like that because the ratio of B/E doping sets the beta

The collector has the weakest doping level so that the depletion layer will be large so that it can handle a large reverse voltage. Remember that  in the active region the BC junction is reverse biased !

The **thickness** of the base must be small, the base must be thin because the carriers coming from the emitter should be have already passed through the base and enter the collector region before they realize:

*Oh, oops ! Too late to recombine in the base*.

And, *Oh, blast now we're pulled to the collector contact* (because that will have a large positive voltage, for an NPN that is).

That is what makes the base current small and forces the carriers to go to the collector instead of recombining in the base.

The **depletion region** in the base will be **smaller** than the depletion region in the collector because the base has a higher doping level ! Your assumption that the base has a lighter doping than the collector is not true. It is the collector that has the lightest doping.

Comment: In the Same article it is written that the doping level of collector is intermediate between highly doped emitter and lightly doped base. Also my text book says the same thing. I am confused?

Comment: Wikibooks says the same(The doping of base is just one tenth of that of collector. )                                          https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Semiconductor_Electronics/Bipolar_Junction_Transistor

Comment: Then I think those sources are also confused, look here: http://icosym.cvut.cz/course/semicond/node41.html at the figure 3.8. This is a typical doping structure of an on-chip BJT. The collector doping also depends on what max Vce you want the transistor to have. For the base operation of the transistor, only base and emitter doping ratios are relevant.

Comment: I think concentration of doping is more in base because of less thickness, but actually it is less doped than collector, even though it is less doped than collector the less thickness of base makes sure that it has more concentration. Now this explains everything. What you think Bimpelrekkie?

Comment: Doping level and thickness are actually unrelated. Any combination is possible. Not every combination will give the best performing transistor though. So don't couple the two.

Comment: Adding to this. You want to minimize an effect known as "base-width modulation". This effect manifests itself as Ic dependence on Vce. What happens is that by varying Vce, you modulate the width of the CB depletion region. This allows the diffusing minority carriers in the base to reach the collector. If the base effectively looks shorter, more make it, if it looks longer, less make it. To minimize this we'd like the change in the depletion region width to occur mostly in the collector. Hence we ensure that the collector is doped more lightly than the base.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken. It is so because the doping level is emitter > base > collector.

In the active mode of transistor, the depletion layer is weakened slightly by the additional holes in the middle layer. The barrier is now low so that electrons can diffuse into the depletion layer to reach the point at which they are pulled to the collector by the electric fields inside of the transistor. This makes the width at collector side more and at base side less.

Hence, the electrons can now move from the emitter to the collector. The transistor became conductive across the emitter-collector line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stand firmly on two grounds if you  want to remove your doubt.

They are:-

1) the doping levels of various sections of transistor.
2) the biasing of different sections.
Lets cover them one by one.

The doping levels of various sections are :
Emitter>base >collector

And the **EB** junction is usually forward biased and $CB$ junction is reversed biased.

Since the EB junction is forward biased so charge carriers moves towards the junction. Now since the base  is lightly doped recombination does not takes place appreciably in the base region .**And a large amount charge carriers are attracted towards the collector due to its high biasing applied to its junction.**

Since the CB region is reverse biased heavily (**by heavily i mean the potential across CB region is very high**) while the EB region is forward biased lightly so the depletion region should be more on the CB region as compared to EB region .

And The depletion region is more diffused to the collector side because it is less doped than the base.

Hope this helps!

Comment: *And The depletion region is more diffused to the collector side because it is more doped than the base.* You mean, because the collector is less doped that the base.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes i mean collector is less doped that the base.